# Determining the result of two increasing functions

Tags: calculus

I believe that my answer to the following is correct, but would like some verification as well as logic as to the right answer if possible.

I believe that the answer to the following is true: If $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are both increasing functions, then $f(x) = p(x) + q(x)$ must be increasing.

I reason that it is true because two functions with positive slopes added together cannot create a negative slope. Therefore $f(x)$ must also have a positive slope.

Would this logic be true?

Comment: Your intuition is correct but you need to formalize the idea better than this. A function $f$ is increasing if whenever $x_1 < x_2$, then $f(x_1)< f(x_2)$. If $p$ and $q$ are both increasing, what do you know about $p(x_1)+q(x_1)$ in relation to $p(x_2)+q(x_2)$?

Comment: I appreciate the help all. This turns out to be much simpler than I was thinking it to be. Must be time for a study break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct if "slope" is meaningful, that is, if you are talking about differentiable functions.  But the more general case is in fact easier to prove.

Suppose that $p(x)$ is increasing.  This means:

> if $x_1<x_2$, then $p(x_1)<p(x_2)$.

Suppose the same for $q(x)$.  Then if $x_1<x_2$ we have
$$f(x_1)=p(x_1)+q(x_1)<p(x_2)+q(x_2)=f(x_2)\ ,$$
so $f(x)$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You know that
$$
a\leq b \Rightarrow p(a)\leq p(b)
$$
$$
a\leq b \Rightarrow q(a)\leq q(b)
$$ then **by summing**
$$
p(a)+q(a)\leq p(b)+q(b)
$$ that is
$$
a\leq b \Rightarrow f(a)\leq f(b).
$$

Answer (score 0):

A positive slope is only an intuition: function(s) may be uncontinuous. But simple calculations show the desired result.

If $x_1<x_2$, then  $p(x_1)<p(x_2)$ and $q(x_1)<q(x_2)$, and we can add both inequalities.